# How do I hook up my Gamecube to my Desktop?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

So I bought an PC/LAPTOP VGA SVGA TO S-Video 3 RCA Composite AV TV Out Converter Adapter Cable
to play my GameCube on my Monitor but I can figure out how to Switch it? This is where I got the Cable. http://www.ebay.com/itm/351233132129?_trksid=p2059210.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Answer (score 2):

The cable you bought it meant to work in the other direction. It's supposed to convert a VGA video signal output from a PC into composite (or S-Video) video output that you can connect to a TV. In other words it would allow you to connect your desktop PC to a TV.

You need a converter that will convert composite video (or maybe S-Video if you have an S-Video cable for your GameCube) to VGA, HDMI or DVI depending on what inputs your monitor has available.

Answer (score 0):

That cable you have is not going to work with your GameCube. You can not convert passively an RCA output to an VGA. You need some sort of converter box (active!)

Something like: [Link in Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016SN49Y)

Comment: The device you linked converts from component video to HDMI, but it's unlikely he has a GameCube component cable. Component cables for the GameCube were rare and expensive, as they weren't passive devices.

Answer (score -1):

U shouldn't have to get a converter for rca to VGA since there both analog same with DVI , anything that has a digital signal like DVI+d ,HDMI, ygbr , just remember that digital to analog doesn't need a converter ,but analog to digital does need a converter . yea converters can be Uber expensive

Comment: What are you talking about? The video signal in RCA is a single cable, while VGA is 15 pins, splitting the RGB signals. There's no way you can take a single signal and split it into 3 without processing.